# If statement for page template in node template file

Tags: 7, theming

Is it at all possible to check for a page template NID before outputting some text in a custom node template file?

I have a custom node template file and I am using that data in a custom page template file. I have checked in the past the NID of a node using the following that that works:

```
          if (($node->nid) == '25732') { 
            print views_embed_view('lead_view',"page"); 
          }
```

Now I want to check whether the page template file is 1234. I tried using $page, but I don't think that is right.

```
          if (($page->nid) == '1234') { 
            **Stuff here** 
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this like

```
if(arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == '1234'){
**Stuff here** 
}
```